# Latin hypercube sampling with python

Tags: python, random, sampling

I would like to sample a distribution defined by a function in multiple dimensions (2,3,4):

```
f(x, y, ...) = ...
```

The distributions might be ugly, non standard (like a 3D spline on data, sum of gaussians ect.). To this end I would like to uniformly sample the 2..4 dimensional space, and than with an additional random number accept or reject the given point of the space into my sample.

1. Is there a ready to use python lib for this purpose?
2. Is there python lib for generating the points in this 2..4 dimensional space with latin hypercube sampling, or with other uniform sampling method? Bruteforce sampling with independent random numbers usually results in more and less dense regimes of the space.
3. if 1) and 2) doesn't exist, is there anybody who is kind enough to share his implementation for the same or similar problem.

I'll use it in a python code, but links to other solutions are also acknowledged.

Answer (score 11):

I guess this is a late answer, but this is also for future visitors. I have just put up [an implementation of multi-dimensional uniform Latin Hypercube sampling](https://github.com/sahilm89/lhsmdu) on git. It is minimal, but very easy to use. You can generate uniform random variables sampled in n dimensions using Latin Hypercube Sampling, if your variables are independent. Below is an example plot comparing Monte Carlo and Latin Hypercube Sampling with Multi-dimensional Uniformity (LHS-MDU) in two dimensions with zero correlation.

```
import lhsmdu
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

l = lhsmdu.sample(2,10) # Latin Hypercube Sampling of two variables, and 10 samples each.
k = lhsmdu.createRandomStandardUniformMatrix(2,10) # Monte Carlo Sampling

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_xticks(numpy.arange(0,1,0.1))
ax.set_yticks(numpy.arange(0,1,0.1))
plt.scatter(k[0], k[1], color="b", label="LHS-MDU")
plt.scatter(l[0], l[1], color="r", label="MC")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: MCS versus LHS]

Comment: This fails right away for me: ndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.  The failing line is l = lhsmdu.sample(2, 10)  (i'm on python 3)

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera Sorry for the late reply. This currently works only with Python 2.7, I don't mind spending some time making it compatible with Python 3, if you are still planning to use it.

Comment: I have no urgency for using the library now, but if you port it to python 3, I’ll definitely use it.

Comment: Okay. It should work now, assuming that you have all the dependencies right. Could you check it out?

Comment: I tried to pip install 'lhsmdu' but there is no module under this name.

Comment: It wasn't on pip earlier. I have put it up now. Could you check once again?

Answer (score 8):

Latin Hypercube sampling is now part of SciPy since version 1.7. See the [doc](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.stats.qmc.LatinHypercube.html#scipy.stats.qmc.LatinHypercube).

```py
from scipy.stats.qmc import LatinHypercube

engine = LatinHypercube(d=2)
sample = engine.random(n=100)
```

It support centering, strength and optimization.

Answer (score 6):

Now the pyDOE library provides a tool to generate Latin-hypercube-based samples.

https://pythonhosted.org/pyDOE/randomized.html

to generate samples over n dimensions:

```
lhs(n, [samples, criterion, iterations])
```

where n is the number of dimensions, samples as the total number of the sample space.

Comment: How do I specify a seed value so I get the same results everytime?

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, but I save these values in a text file so that I can use later on. Personally, I have not checked it the results vary between attempts, but think might be good idea to have a copy in my hard drive.

Comment: The problem with that is that I don't know my 'n' and 'p' arguments before hand. 
However, I was able to solve my problem without modifying the pyDOE source code, by importing numpy in my main script after I import pyDOE and then executing numpy.random.seed(seed_value). This ensures that the numbers are the same between runs.

Comment: pyDOE2 is a fork of pyDOE that is still being maintained. One improvement it has is that you can pass a random seed in directly to `lhs`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an update of Sahil M's answer for Python 3 (update from Python 2 to Python 3 and some minor code changes to match code and figure):

```
import lhsmdu
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

l = lhsmdu.sample(2,10) # Latin Hypercube Sampling of two variables, and 10 samples each.
k = lhsmdu.createRandomStandardUniformMatrix(2,10) # Monte Carlo Sampling

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_xticks(numpy.arange(0,1,0.1))
ax.set_yticks(numpy.arange(0,1,0.1))
plt.scatter([k[0]], [k[1]], color="r", label="MC")
plt.scatter([l[0]], [l[1]], color="b", label="LHS-MDU")
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: code visual output]

I once encountered a Python memory error running this script. Any suggestions why this could happen or how to changes the script so it doesn't happen anymore in the future?

Comment: More information is required to answer this question. Could you please post it as a new question or as an issue on Github?

Comment: Yep, I'll do it. For small samples it's doing great. Just for larger samples or/and more variables, it crashes sometimes or it takes a looooong time to generate it (which is acceptable regarding the complex operations but yeah a bit more power would be useful)

Comment: In case somebody pops by here on this answer, [the algorithm](https://github.com/sahilm89/lhsmdu) has been updated and now runs about 20 times faster.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yet, too slow to generate 9D 1000 samples.

Answer (score 1):

This 2-D example samples uniformly on two dimensions, chooses each point with constant probability (thus keeping a binomially distributed number of points), selects randomly and without replacement those points from the sample space,  and generates a pair of vectors which you can then pass through to your function f:

```
import numpy as np
import random
resolution = 10
keepprob = 0.5
min1, max1 = 0., 1.
min2, max2 = 3., 11. 
keepnumber = np.random.binomial(resolution * resolution, keepprob,1)
array1,array2  = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(min1,max1,resolution),np.linspace(min2,max2,resolution))
randominixes  = random.sample(list(range(resolution * resolution)), int(keepnumber))
randominixes.sort()
vec1Sampled,vec2Sampled  = array1.flatten()[randominixes],array2.flatten()[randominixes]
```