# Is there a python equivalent to Matlab function lhsnorm?

Tags: python, matlab, random

I am trying to obtain stratified random samples from a normal distribution.

On Matlab this is as simple as X = lhsnorm (mu, sigma, n)

Mathworks documentation: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/lhsnorm.html

Is there an equivalent way to do this in python?

Comment: Possibly helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884361/latin-hypercube-sampling-from-a-normal-distribution-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137195/latin-hypercube-sampling-with-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latin hypercube sampling with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137195/latin-hypercube-sampling-with-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latin Hypercube Sampling from a normal distribution (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884361/latin-hypercube-sampling-from-a-normal-distribution-python)

Answer (score 0):

use numpy package and type:

np.random.normal(mu, sigma, n)