# equivalent of lhsnorm(mu,sigma,n) in python

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, sampling, montecarlo

Does anyone know how to generate a latin hyper cube sampling of a multivariate distribution with mean, and covariance specified in python. It would be the equivalent of the X = lhsnorm (mu, sigma, n) in matlab. The answer provided here ( [Is there a python equivalent to Matlab function lhsnorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173551/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-matlab-function-lhsnorm)) does not address the question. It simply returns multivariate normal samples just like same as using . R = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,n) as seen here https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnrnd.html in matlab.

Comment: Perhaps https://pythonhosted.org/pyDOE/randomized.html ?

Comment: i have also looked at the pyDOE/randomized, it generates LHS samples but does not give the option of introducing correlated multivariate samples via the mean and covariance matrices.